# Locale setting on a Red Hat box

Tags: java, redhat, localization

Recently our organization got a couple of server boxes which are I guess present in some data-center in UK. The problem is that for some reason the default `Locale` representation in Java on that server returns `en_US` instead of the expected `en_GB` (I confirmed this by running a code on that server which simply outputs `Locale.default()`). I am pretty sure this has got something to do the way in which the boxes were set up.

My question is: what would be the approach to fix this issue now that the OS has been installed? Is there any way I can for a given SSH session set the locale as `en_GB` instead of the current `en_US`?

TIA,
sasuke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/10/change-location-on-cent-os-redhat.html

may help you setup your said location

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. For some reason it seems that setting the TZ variable has no effect on the default Locale returned by Java. Even after doing `export TZ=Asia/Tokyo`, the default locale returned is `en_US`.

Comment: You can make this change permanent for yourself by appending the line
 `TZ='Asia/Tokyo'; export TZ`
to the file '.profile' in your home directory; then log out and log in again.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried changing the LANG environment variable in /etc/sysconfig/i18n ?

Comment: But that doesn't seem to be a per user configuration, right? I mean like I can change the format of the time shown by commands like `ls` by changing the environment variable `TZ`, can I change the locale on a per-ssh-session basis by setting some environment variable?